# package authorindex supported?

Tags: authorindex

I use the authorindex package for the book I'm writing (not yet in Overleaf).  It requires running a perl script as part of the compile sequence.  Does Overleaf have support for such things, or a better alternative?

Comment: Probably not. Most likely this requires the `--shell-escape` option to be active during compilation - and that could be dangerous running on an active server.

Comment: ...I may be wrong. See [Examples, techniques and tips on how to use `latexmkrc` with Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/216-examples-techniques-and-tips-on-how-to-use-latexmkrc-with-overleaf#.VmtS2vnR_Dc).

Comment: @ OP Welcome!  @Werner It need not require shell escape if it is just needed during the compile sequence, but only if it is needed during compilation itself. If you see what I mean. In that sense, `biber` is part of the compilation sequence, but it is not needed during compilation itself i.e. it is run before or after `pdflatex` etc. I don't know the package, so I don't know which of these is required.